# Excel VBA - clear content to the last used cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Worksheets("happy").Unprotect
Range("C4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range("C4:BB100").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

I want to clear the range from `C4` to the last used cell which constantly changes.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: The last used cell of the column C or the last used cell in the worksheet?

Comment: last used cell oin activesheet

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt.

```
Sub del_range()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("happy")
'ws.Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column)).Select
ws.Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

The commented line would just select it, but i recommend not doing that because select needs time.
It looks in which line the last value in this sheet is and in which column is the last value and deletes all from cell C4 to last row and cell.

Comment: but then when i delete one more time, the cell (4,3) is not the cell. the deleted area is shifting upwards. is there any way that i can just stick to the area selection no matter how many times i clicked

Comment: Does it delete/select some content before C4 to C4 or how does the selections look? If you deleted all the content the last used cell has to be before C4 so it should select something like F3 to C4

Answer (score 0):

### The Range from a Cell to the Last Cell

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub clearHappy()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("happy")
        '.Unprotect
        With .Range("C4")
            Dim rg As Range:
            Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
                .Worksheet.Columns.Count - .Column + 1)
            'Debug.Print rg.Address
            Dim cel As Range
            Set cel = rg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                'Debug.Print cel.Address
                Set rg = rg.Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1, _
                    rg.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column _
                    - .Column + 1)
                'Debug.Print rg.Address
                rg.ClearContents
            End If
        End With
        '.Protect
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i just want a formula to loop in first row but the last column of used cell in Row 3. can u help on this as well. 

my formula is =IFNA(HLOOKUP(A3,Coco!3:5,3,FALSE),"NIL")"